# How do trigger a transionend event after another transitionend event triggered?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

My second transitionend doesnt get triggered at all and my first transitionend gets triggered to early.

I want to let a div transform to the left out of the window and when finished display none and transform it to the right out of the window. After that finished I want to set display to inline-block and Transform it back to the window.

But when I try it the first transitionend gets triggered to early and the second one doesn't get triggered at all.

```
const nameBox = document.getElementById("nameBox");
    nameBox.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
    nameBox.addEventListener("transitionend", (event) => {
            nameBox.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
            nameBox.style.display = "none";
            nameBox.addEventListener("transitionend", (event) => {
                    nameBox.style.display = "inline-block";
                    nameBox.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
             });
    });
```

```
#nameBox{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 95%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: #231123;
    color: white; 
    font-size: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: You end up with two event listeners on the same event. The second one will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably CSS animations (see below).
If for some reason you need to use transitions instead, the following JS seems to work. You need a named function so that the event listener can be removed afterwards, otherwise it will transition forever.

```
const nameBox = document.getElementById("nameBox");

nameBox.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
nameBox.addEventListener("transitionend", slideBackIn);

function slideBackIn() {
  nameBox.style.transition = "none";
  nameBox.style.transform = "translateX(110%)";
  nameBox.getBoundingClientRect(); //force reflow, makes the browser render the previous line immediately

  nameBox.style.transition = "1.5s ease-in-out";
  nameBox.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";

  nameBox.removeEventListener("transitionend", slideBackIn);
}
```

I moved it 110% to the right because it looked better in my browser. In place of getBoundingClientRect you could use anything that forces a browser reflow. If you don't force a reflow, the browser will skip moving the box to the right and send it straight to the center.

If you do it with [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations), you don't need  the hacky reflow thing, or any JS at all. The CSS looks like this. (If you leave out the animation-timing-function lines then it will race back across the page very fast, which sort of works but doesn't seem like a great idea. The 0% keyframe isn't necessary, I just like including it for clarity.)

```
#nameBox {
  /* transition: 1.5s ease-in-out; */
  animation: slide-out-in 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes slide-out-in {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-100%);
    animation-timing-function: step-start;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translate(110%);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%);
  }
}
```